# I want to remove particular element in listview in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $(".list").live("click", function(e) {
                $('#buran').append('<li  data-corners="false" class="live ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-corner-bottom ui-li-last ui-btn-up-e" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#" class="list ui-link-inherit">' + $(this).text() + '</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></div></li>');
                $('#buran').listview('refresh');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I want to remove the current element when i append the event?

Comment: You want to remove `.list` or you want to remove `.buran li` ?